# How to get jQuery UI datepicker to close on outside click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have looked around and tried some stuff already from what I have found and nothing seems to be working.

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="custom_st" id="start_date" class="tb fl hasDatepicker">
```

I tried the below...

```
$("#start_date").blur(function(e) { $(this).datepicker("hide"); });
```

...and I thought it worked, until I discovered that this obviously applies to the `text field` - so yes, when you click outside the datepicker *will* close, but if you click anything *else* on the datepicker it will *also* close - such as the little arrow buttons to go forward/back a month.

Then I tried this..

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).parents().filter('.ui-dialog').length) {
        $('#start_date').datepicker("hide");
    }
});
```

..but then realized this obviously won't work either as as soon as you click it it opens and *then* closes again because you triggered the click function to close it.

Reading another SO question someone mentioned it may have a problem when used in conjunction with the [jQuery selectbox plugin](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox) of which I am also using.

I tried this but it didn't work either.. `ui-datepicker-div` is the ID of the containing element of the datepicker.

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div').blur(function() {
    //$('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
    $('#start_date').datepicker("hide");
});
```

Is there any other way to close it?

Comment: you could be lazy and just add a click handler to the body tag, and then prevent it if the click is within the datepicker.  e.target should let you figure that out.

Comment: The jQuery UI datepicker widget [already has that behavior by default](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/eggplant/jquery-ui.css) ...

Comment: @Pointy that's not how it behaves on my site, that's why I mentioned the selectbox plugin, so I need an alternative way of closing it.

Comment: @Brett yes it's definitely that plugin. It's catching "mousedown" events and always canceling event propagation. I would consider that to be a serious bug. That plugin is also coded with some deprecated jQuery APIs (`.live()`). You might want to look for an alternative, or fix it yourself.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks. I only have intermediate JS knowledge so I don't like my chances of fixing it myself; I know of a decent alternative but with the amount of work I have already put in integrating this plugin throughout our site it's not something I really want to do - that is, change plugins.

Comment: Well you might try just commenting out the call to `e.stopPropagation()` on line 304 of the plugin (the non-minified version) and see if that helps, just as an experiment.

Comment: Even the jquery-ui datepicker demo doesn't close the datepicker if you click outside the iframe that its contained in.  This can be worked around but they don't explain how on their site.  Are you using iframes?

Comment: @pointy Do you mean the `selectbox` plugin? What does that do exactly and what affects do you think it will have on the selectboxes?

Comment: @rooster It closes for me. Not using iframes.

Comment: Yes, the selectbox plugin. That line of code causes the "mousedown" events *outside* the selectbox's "property" to effectively be canceled. That means that the mechanism that's set up for the date picker can't work properly.

Comment: You can leave in the next line of code, the one that closes the selectbox. That's OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
  var ele = $(e.toElement);  
  if (!ele.hasClass("hasDatepicker") && !ele.hasClass("ui-datepicker") && !ele.hasClass("ui-icon") && !$(ele).parent().parents(".ui-datepicker").length) 
    $(".hasDatepicker").datepicker("hide"); 
});
```